# REPEATED + REQUIRED field in BigQUery schema

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the [BigQuery schema documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas/) BigQuery supports the following modes for columns: Nullable, Required, and Repeated.
Is there any way to make field (with type Record) Required and Repeated at the same time?

At the moment I have:

[image]

```
insert into test (id) values('333')
```

[image]

Comment: Arrays cannot be null (only empty) within BigQuery tables, so it doesn't make sense to support the `NOT NULL` annotation for them. If the question is how to enforce that arrays have at least one element, this is not possible currently.

Answer (score 1):

For arrays REQUIRED is not supported.
See [DDL reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#column_name_and_column_schema):

> (...) supports an optional NOT NULL constraint for types other than ARRAY.

```
column_schema :=
   {simple_type [NOT NULL] |
    STRUCT<field_list> [NOT NULL] |
    ARRAY<array_element_schema>}
   [OPTIONS(column_option_list)]
```

So, it's only supported for simple types and STRUCT/RECORD

You could start a feature request, though: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149